# how do I use structured cues in html5 video tag texttracks?

Tags: html5-video

I see that a text-track file can have an entry like this:

```
multicell
00:01:15.200 --> 00:02:18.800
{
"title" : "Multi-celled organisms"
"description" : "Multi-celled organisms have different types of cells that perform specialized functions."
}
```

I'm not actually using text-track files, instead I'm using javascript to create "cues" for a texttrack object that is not in a file.  But the question is, if I play a video with a track that has structured cues like these, do any subtitles appear?
ideally, I would have the "description" field appear as subtitles, and separately I'd catch the contents of the "title" field and so something else with it.  (I could do that in an event).  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put together a small [cue-example](http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/tLubr/) for you.

To answer your questions:

1. How to make a track visible
   a) The track has to be a 'subtitles' or 'captions' kind.
   b) The track has to be in mode 'showing'

   //add a subtitle track to a video

   var track = $('video').get(0).addTextTrack('subtitles', 'just a test', 'en');

   //make it visible

   track.mode = 'showing';
2. structured Data

The Cue always has textual information and will always show the hole text. Of course you can parse a JSON string and do whatever you want with it. In case you are generating cues programatically. You won't need to add JSON. You can pass the description text directly to the cue constructor and then simply extend the resulting cue with a custom property.

```
function createStructuredCues(s, e, obj){
    var cue = new TextTrackCue(s, e, obj.description);
    cue.customMetaData = obj;
    return cue;
}
```